# Tutorial for using R to do multivariate regression?

Tags: r, data-visualization, references, multivariate-analysis

I am a programmer who, in a past life, used the products RS/1, RS/Explore, and RS/Discover in a manufacturing engineer career.  Now, years later, I would like to do some multivariate regression on some real-world data (sales data from my wife's store).  The point would be to highlight what sales days are truly exceptional, not just part of the normal distribution, after taking into account month, day of week, weather, etc.

If I still had access to RS/1 and associated products, I'd know how to do this, but that is not the case, so I'm thinking I'd want to use R.  However, most R tutorials I have found just cover the very basics, and don't get to the point of multivariate regression.  Can you recommend an R tutorial that takes one past the basics of plotting a histogram, etc. into in-depth analysis of real-world ad-hoc data, presumably using multi-variate regression?

Comment: Are you interested in univariate multiple regression (one predicted variable) or multivariate multiple regression (many predicted variables analyzed simultaneously)?

Comment: Good question; I am interested in both but could make do with univariate multiple regression (and use multiple models for different output variables of interest).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my favorite one: [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html)

Comment: @M.-Tibbits nice link and simple tutorial, with some good links under "Going Further" at the end.

Comment: Beware of the recommendation for `cv.lm()` from package `DAAG` for k-fold cross-validation though. It silently uses only the first predictor in the validation, i.e., is only suitable for simple linear regression. As is mentioned in its help file, use `CVlm()`instead.

Answer (score 6):

+1 for Quick-R.

Another great resource that I (re)turn to regularly is the website of the [UCLA Statistical Consulting Group](http://scc.stat.ucla.edu/). In particular, it sounds like you might find their [data analysis examples](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/dae/) useful. Many of the cases walk through the logic of inquiry and model design steps in addition to providing sample code and datasets. They also have a separate section of [textbook examples and code](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/examples/), which I have found useful for self-teaching purposes.

Comment: I __love__ the UCLA site.  I tell my students taking SAS to go there if they've seen/used a different piece of software, but I didn't know they had compiled as extensive of a section on R.  Splendid!

Comment: I marked the Quick-R answer from M. Tibbits as "accepted answer" but also upvoted this one as this also looks like a great resource which Google had not led me to.  Thanks!